# Interface NFC reader acr122u with web applications

Tags: java, jsp, webforms

I have created the web Forms using JSP and I need to Read a data from a smart card.

Comment: Good.. all the best on that :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to plug-in javascript hooks like in Android webview, then this is actually not that hard. Here is a [proof of concept](https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api/tree/master/externalNFCWebKiosk).